# Android still uses old ip when resolving hostname

Tags: networking, ip-address

I have a weird problem here.

I use ftp to exchange files between my smartphone (Xperia Z5 compact) and my pc. A while back the pc had a static ip address but now it's assigned one via dhcp. When I try to connect to the pc from the phone by way of the pc's hostname it still uses the old static ip the pc once had.

Any ideas as to what I can do about this?

Comment: Are you root? Which FTP server app/program you use? Your PC's old IP must be saved in FTP server's cache. Try resetting server app by clearing data. Or check your /etc/hosts file if an entry is added there.

Comment: No, I don't have root access. I use Total Commander's FTP plugin. The problem doesn't only occur with the FTP client. When I use the terminal emulator and ping my pc its hostname only gets "resolved" to its old ip address. /etc/hosts just contains the standard localhost entries.

Comment: Clear arp entries

Comment: How do I do that on Android?

Comment: That command is not found on my phone.

Comment: Busybox arp only works on rooted devices, it seems.

Comment: At least you can identify the problem without root. 'cat /proc/net/arp' does the same. ARP related problems should be fixed on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You can  clear `arp cache` using this command in terminal:

```
ip -s -s neigh flush all
```

(or simply `ip neigh flush 192.168.xx.0/yy` if you know the network range)

While not necessary, you may need to reboot the device, ping the hostname again and see if its resolved to new IP.

Looking from the other side, you can try resetting winsock entries and TCP/IP stack for the PC and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks, the command works, but the problem still remains. I think this may be a router problem.